# Using pure swift to get users location for an App Clip

Tags: ios, swift, apple-appclips

I have a Swift project that I want to add App Clip to. The project needs to know the users location. I can use Location Service to ask the user to use their location, but for a better experience I would prefer to use 'App Clip's 'Request location Confirmation'.

In all examples, which are all swiftUI, it seems to be using `userActivity.appClipActivationPayload`. However in my ViewController viewDidLoad, when I try to get the userActivity from UIApplication.shared it is nil.

```
let userActivity = UIApplication.shared.userActivity
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: Are you using an app delegate or scene delegate?  Can you show the code you have used in the appropriate delegate to get the activity?  See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/responding_to_invocations

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, very helpful. I was trying to do it through AppDelegate. However I need the exact location of the user as I use the app to give direction. I have settled on using LocationManager. This I could us however the AppClip is called, and is not limited to a code at a physical location. (I hope)

Comment: Yes, the location you get through the user activity is just a region that you can use to confirm that the user is located at the store or whatever. For directions you will need to ask for and receive permission to use the users precise location